# Does Objective-C Reference Assigned Fields or Creates New Instances

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-management, reference, field

Say for example I have the following definition of `MyClass`:

```
@interface MyClass
{
    ClassWithBigMemoryUsage* cwbmu;
}

-(void) setClassWithBigMemoryUsage:(ClassWithBigMemoryUsage*) assignment; // where cwbmu = assignment;
```

If I create a `myClassInstance` as a `MyClass` instance and `cwbmuInstance` as a `ClassWithBigMemoryUsage` instance, and then call `[myClassInstance setClassWithBigMemoryUsage:cwbmuInstance]`to set `cwbmuInstance` as a field of `myClassInstance`, will that create a new instance (meaning additional allocated memory) of the object `ClassWithBigMemoryUsage` for `myClassInstance` or will that simply reference `myClassInstance`'s field to `cwbmuInstance` (meaning no additional memory for the object was allocated).

Comment: It all depends.  Does setClassWithBigMemoryUsage implement `strong`/`retain` semantics or `copy` semantics?

Comment: I'm not sure how to answer that, @HotLicks. Hehe. Sorry. Could you please clear `strong`/`retain` or `copy` semantics?

Comment: Are you dealing with a property?  If so, how is it declared?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All Objective-C objects are pointers (hence the `*` in `ClassWithBigMemoryUsage *`), so the object will be passed by reference and you won't have to worry about it getting copied when it is passed.

However, whether or not the object is copied when the method actually does the assignment obviously depends upon the implementation of your setter method. If you just do this:

```
cwbmu = assignment;
```

You'll just set the pointer value, and no copying is done. Of course, since it's an object, you should probably retain it, by doing:

```
[cwbmu autorelease];
cwbmu = [assignment retain];
```

But the result is the same. The only way to truly copy an Objective-C instance reliably is by explicitly sending it a `copy` message:

```
[cwbmu autorelease];
cwbmu = [assignment copy];
```

And this only works on classes that conform to the `NSCopying` protocol.

As a final note, if you're using `@property` declarations, along with `@synthesize`'d methods, you can specify which of these behavior's you'd like. Declaring a property the following three ways will use the three ways described, respectively:

```
@property (assign) ClassWithBigMemoryUsage* cwbmu;
@property (retain) ClassWithBigMemoryUsage* cwbmu;
@property (copy) ClassWithBigMemoryUsage* cwbmu;
```

Also note that under ARC, this memory management is done for you, so you can't control it directly. Instead, you'd use the `weak` option (instead of `assign`) or the `strong` option (instead of `retain`), and even though the old names still work, the new names make it more clear what you're actually doing. The `copy` option is still valid under ARC.

Finally, if you're using ARC, but *not* using `@property`, instance variables are, by default, managed as being `strong`. You can change this by prepending `__weak` to their ivar declaration. However, `weak` is not supported by all architectures, in which case `__unsafe_unretained` may be used instead, but in the latter case, deallocated object pointers will *not* be zeroed (set to `nil`), which they will be when using `__weak`.

Comment: Thanks. I was thinking of the same thing but I just needed confirmation. I'm fairly new to Objective-C so I'm double-doubting my speculations. Haha. Can you please link to a reference for that? I can't find any. Thank you.

Comment: @brain56 Most of these rules are, at a simple level, the same as in plain C. Straight pointer assignment copies the *pointers*, not the values referenced by those pointers. If you're coming from a non-C background (as I know I was when I first learned Obj-C), just think in terms of strong and weak references with respect to object ownership. The biggest mistake you can make in Objective-C memory management is thinking too hard about memory management.